# run gitlab and tomcat through apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, gitlab

I´ve been trying since two days to make tomcat and gitlab work on the same top level domain. my tomcat is running on port `8080` and my gitlab is running on `8081`. when I type `mywebsite.com:8081` I successfully get redirected to gitlab and when I type `mywebsite.com:8080`I get successfully redirected to my tomcat instance. Now I installed `apache 2` and let it run on the port `80` and try to use it as a reverse proxy, but everytime I type `http://www.mywebsite.com/gitlab` I get a 404.

I am using Debian and therefore had to edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`
Inside of this config is this now:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
Servername www.mywebsite.com

<Proxy *>
Order deny, allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /gitlab http://www.mywebsite.com:8081
ProxyPassReverse /gitlab http://www.mywebsite.com:8081
```

Is this not correct? Am I missing something lethal?
Already looked through several instruction guides, but I still cant figure out how to make it work

Edit://

Apache 2Access Log was Empty...

Apache 2 Error log:

```
[Fri Mar 03 08:40:32.654879 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 985:tid 140413383284608] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 03 08:40:32.712726 2017] [core:notice] [pid 985:tid 140413383284608] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 03 08:40:56.608184 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 985:tid 140413383284608] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 03 09:55:19.844429 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 7370:tid 140501655910272] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 03 09:55:19.852533 2017] [core:notice] [pid 7370:tid 140501655910272] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 03 10:03:28.220153 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 7370:tid 140501655910272] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 03 10:42:06.430282 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 14147:tid 140077848672128] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 03 10:42:06.433243 2017] [core:notice] [pid 14147:tid 140077848672128] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 03 11:04:47.177689 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 14147:tid 140077848672128] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 03 11:04:48.289315 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 15822:tid 139992495703936] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 03 11:04:48.289386 2017] [core:notice] [pid 15822:tid 139992495703936] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 03 11:07:07.000803 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 15822:tid 139992495703936] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 03 11:07:08.155106 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 16111:tid 139796633421696] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 03 11:07:08.155170 2017] [core:notice] [pid 16111:tid 139796633421696] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 03 11:18:54.854977 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 16111:tid 139796633421696] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 03 11:18:56.001210 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 17055:tid 139735864428416] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 03 11:18:56.001277 2017] [core:notice] [pid 17055:tid 139735864428416] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 03 11:19:40.649005 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 17055:tid 139735864428416] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 03 11:19:41.757264 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 17230:tid 140277624301440] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 03 11:19:41.757327 2017] [core:notice] [pid 17230:tid 140277624301440] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 03 11:34:57.313779 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 17230:tid 140277624301440] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 03 11:35:50.648583 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 963:tid 140495805245312] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 03 11:35:50.708563 2017] [core:notice] [pid 963:tid 140495805245312] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 03 11:41:29.786364 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 963:tid 140495805245312] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 03 11:41:30.892008 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1854:tid 140138175350656] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 03 11:41:30.892054 2017] [core:notice] [pid 1854:tid 140138175350656] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 03 11:43:54.349607 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1854:tid 140138175350656] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 03 11:43:55.462423 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2137:tid 139958606403456] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 03 11:43:55.462478 2017] [core:notice] [pid 2137:tid 139958606403456] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 03 11:44:44.826290 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2137:tid 139958606403456] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 03 11:50:24.895545 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 989:tid 140278705215360] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 03 11:50:24.935196 2017] [core:notice] [pid 989:tid 140278705215360] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 03 11:53:08.091834 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 989:tid 140278705215360] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 03 11:53:09.210269 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1566:tid 140261252605824] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 03 11:53:09.210324 2017] [core:notice] [pid 1566:tid 140261252605824] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 03 12:08:22.544593 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1566:tid 140261252605824] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 03 12:08:23.651021 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2818:tid 140229764982656] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 03 12:08:23.651070 2017] [core:notice] [pid 2818:tid 140229764982656] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 03 12:17:44.795400 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2818:tid 140229764982656] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 03 12:17:45.967588 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3611:tid 139673959495552] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 03 12:17:45.967642 2017] [core:notice] [pid 3611:tid 139673959495552] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 03 12:33:17.478860 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3611:tid 139673959495552] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 03 12:33:50.519860 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 979:tid 139745101391744] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 03 12:33:50.563235 2017] [core:notice] [pid 979:tid 139745101391744] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 03 12:35:44.783856 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 979:tid 139745101391744] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 03 12:35:47.063628 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 1875:tid 140058368026496] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Mar 03 12:35:47.064726 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1875:tid 140058368026496] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Fri Mar 03 12:35:48.194526 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1875:tid 140058368026496] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.1t configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 03 12:35:48.194669 2017] [core:notice] [pid 1875:tid 140058368026496] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your tags, you are using Apache 2.4. For this, the permission syntax has [changed](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html).

The new syntax would be

```
Require all granted
```

but I don't think this `<Proxy>` block would be needed anyway in the present form.

Comment: removed it, but I am still getting a 404

Comment: Please add the access and  error logs  to your post. And, silly question, did you reload Apache?

Comment: hey, updated my post and yes I always reloaded apache and gitlab